# Apply invert-like color filter to child with ColorFiltered widget

Tags: flutter

I want to invert the color of a certain child within a stack widget using ColorFiltered.

From:
[image: This One]

To:
[image: This]

I had tried playing with the available filter mode but I cannot achieve such an effect yet, can someone tell me how to achieve the invert-like color filter effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
    Colors.white,
    BlendMode.difference,
  ),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Text('Invert Me'),
  ),
),
```

Will do the trick, it will invert the color of its descendants, including photos, videos, or even text.